# Junit test cases for delete operation with try and catch block - handling Exception

Tags: junit, mockito

```java
public UserNoteDefination deleteByNoteCd (UserNoteDefination request, LogDTO log) {
log.setComponent("ClientRequestService.deleteByNoteCd"); 
UserNoteDefination response new UserNoteDefination();

String tabllame = request.getTabName();

String noteCd-request.getNoteCd(); 
if (tabName.equalsIgnoreCase("UND_TABLE"))

{

try

userNoteDefRepository.deleteById(noteCd); 
response.setMsg("Completed");

log.setPayload("[FROM:UI] clientRequest:Delete Successfully");

loggingService.log(GuiServiceConstants.INFO LEVEL, log);

}

catch (Exception e){

response.setMsg("Error");

log.setPayload("[FROM:UI] clientRequest:Error occured while delete");

loggingService.log(GuiServiceConstants.ERROR LEVEL, log);

}

return response;
}
```

This is my junit code in mockito

```java
@Test public void deleteByNoteCd() throws Exception {

LogDTO log = new LogDTO(); log.setComponent("ClientRequestService.getClientRequest");

UserNoteDefination response = new UserNoteDefination();

response.setNoteCd("TEST7");

response.setMsg("Completed");

response.setTabName("UND TABLE");

UserNoteDefination rval - service.deleteByNoteCd(response, log);

assertNotNull(rval);
}
```

I'm unable to cover the exception part. Cab someone help